# What are the logistics behind sending Jaegers into battle?

Tags: warfare, mecha, pacific-rim, kaiju

Logistics is an underrated aspect of warfare and many see it as the most important part about going to war. When the Nazis were making their way into the USSR and were forced to fight in the brutal Russian winter, many soldiers on both sides died due to a lack of rations and in the case of the Nazis, they’d have trouble fueling both their trucks and the Luftwaffe since fuel would freeze and many Heer soldiers didn’t have adequate clothing or protection from the elements. The US military is hailed as the greatest or one of the greatest masters of logistics for a while now due to the fact that we can do everything from moving thousands of troops and military assets to fight a war an entire ocean and continent away while also sending goddamn McDonalds and ice cream over to an active war zone w/o much trouble or impact.

So this leads me to ask: what are the logistics behind sending the Jaegers into battle against the Kaiju? There’s obviously a lot of coordination between LOCCENT, J-Tech, service and support personnel who are on the ground, the air wing that has to physically send the Jaegers off to wherever, etc. But what else is there?

Comment: "The US military is hailed as the greatest or one of the greatest masters of logistics for a while now due to the fact that we" - I wonder if it's worth replacing this "we" by a "they"?